# primefaces org.primefaces.component.diagram override

Tags: primefaces, jsplumb

I have a problem with org.primefaces.component.diagram, i want to add an action when click on any overlay or connector, i make this using jquery, but the problem is that there is no identifier for the connection, after search i was able to get the ids of the 2 end points of the connection but if there is many connection between the same points then i cannot distinguish between them, i tried to override the diagram and add "connectionId" attribute on the connection but i got an exception in the front end :

**Uncaught ReferenceError: connectionId590236 is not defined at eval (eval at  (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=5.2:14), :1:1488)**
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoV6a.jpg)

Comment: The question is not very clear here, what do you mean by "connection", you may post some code snippets to describe the problem more.

Comment: diagram is a prime faces component
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/diagram/basic.xhtml
to draw the diagram i have to fill the model "its value", the model have two main properties : list of elements and list of connection, where the connections are the connection between the elements.

<p:diagram id="topologyViewArea" styleClass="ui-widget-content"
var="el" value="#{topologyGraphicsHandlerBean.topologyGraphicsHelper.model}" >

the connection list are filled in the back end and rendered automatically, i am not able to set and id for example or any other identifier for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found an acceptable solution :

-> add an label overlay on the connection and set the identifier on it.

```
org.primefaces.model.diagram.Connection conn = new org.primefaces.model.diagram.Connection(
            EndPointA, EndPointB);

LabelOverlay labelOverlay = new LabelOverlay(connection.getId(), "labelOverlayClass", 0.3);
    conn.getOverlays().add(labelOverlay);
```

-> then add JS function to handle on dbclick action on the connection and get the id from its related overlay using the classes "._jsPlumb_overlay" and "._jsPlumb_hover"

```
<p:remoteCommand name="connectionClicked"
    actionListener="#{yourBean.onConnectionDoubleClick}" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var connectionId;

    $('._jsPlumb_connector').on('dblclick', function(e) {

        $('._jsPlumb_overlay._jsPlumb_hover').each(function() {
            connectionId =  $(this).text();
        });

        connectionClicked([ { name : 'connectionId', value : connectionId } ]);
    });
    });
</script>
```

-> finally in the bean you extract the id and do whatever you want

```
public void onConnectionDoubleClick() {
    Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

    String connectionId = params.get("connectionId");

    if(StringUtils.isBlank(connectionId))
        return;

    .........
```

Answer (score 4):

The closet solution would be is to use `setId` on `Element` in the `DefaultDiagramModel` creation.

An example would be as the following:

```java
    Element elementA = new Element("A", "20em", "6em");
    elementA.setId("element-a");

    Element elementB = new Element("B", "10em", "18em");
    elementB.setId("element-b");


    Element elementC = new Element("C", "40em", "18em");
    elementC.setId("element-c");
    ...
```

Since PrimeFaces doesn't provide the control you are searching for, and the original component comes from [jsPlumb](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/), you may rely on that to achieve what you are looking for.

First make sure that the `<p:diagram>` has a `widgetVar` value, es. `diagramWV`

An example would be the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  //timeout makes sure the component is initialized
  setTimeout(function () {
    for (var key in PF('diagramWV').canvas.getAllConnections()) {

        if (PF('diagramWV').canvas.getAllConnections().hasOwnProperty(key)) {

            //Elemenets Events
            // on source just once
            $(PF('diagramWV').canvas.getAllConnections()[key].source).off('click').on('click', function () {
                console.log($(this).attr('id'))
            });
            // on target just once
            $(PF('diagramWV').canvas.getAllConnections()[key].target).off('click').on('click', function () {
                console.log($(this).attr('id'))
            });

            //Connection Event
            PF('diagramWV').canvas.getAllConnections()[key].bind("click", function (conn) {
                console.log("source " + conn.sourceId);
                console.log("target " + conn.targetId);
            });
        }
    }
  }, 500);
});
```

Note: The `canvas` property of the widgetVar is the current instance of [jsPlumbInstance](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/apidocs/classes/jsPlumbInstance.html)

Here's an online [demo](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/DailyLab/diagram/main.xhtml), and a small working example on [github](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/diagram/main.xhtml).

Comment: Cool, great answer. Maybe add a feature request to PF to incorporate this in their releases

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i think it is a good solution, but it will solve the problem if there is only one connection between each 3 elements, but if there are more than one connection, i have to add an identifier for each of them separately.

Comment: I guess the identifier would be source + target, if I'm getting you right, it's the connection after all.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add a click event to Overlay by extending the primefaces Overlay class. If you make a change to the toJS() class (taking heavy inspiration from the Primefaces LabelOverLay) then you can write your own overlay with the [jsplumb overlay constructor](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/events.html#overlayEvents). Here's my implementation of a ClickableLabelOverlay.

```
public class ClickableLabelOverlay implements Overlay {
    private String label;
    private String styleClass;
    private double location = 0.5;
    private String onClick;

    public ClickableLabelOverlay() {
    }

    public ClickableLabelOverlay(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public ClickableLabelOverlay(String label, String styleClass, double location, String onClick) {
        this(label);
        this.styleClass = styleClass;
        this.location = location;
        this.onClick = onClick;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getStyleClass() {
        return styleClass;
    }

    public void setStyleClass(String styleClass) {
        this.styleClass = styleClass;
    }

    public double getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(double location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getOnClick() {
        return onClick;
    }

    public void setOnClick(String onClick) {
        this.onClick = onClick;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return "Label";
    }

    public String toJS(StringBuilder sb) {
        sb.append("['Label',{label:'").append(label).append("'");

        if(styleClass != null) sb.append(",cssClass:'").append(styleClass).append("'");
        if(location != 0.5) sb.append(",location:").append(location);
        if(onClick != null) sb.append(",events:{click:function(labelOverlay, originalEvent){").append(onClick).append("}}");

        sb.append("}]");

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Put any javascript you want to execute inside of the onClick variable and it'll run when you click on the overlay. For convenience I added it to the set of default overlays for my diagram.

```
diagram.getDefaultConnectionOverlays().add(new ClickableLabelOverlay(...)
```